# How to use H tags correctly if child elements are more important than parents

Tags: html

I'm updating one of my old site to html5 and I'm a little bit confused even after reading a lots of articles, how to use the h tags correctly.

As the title says the children are more important than the parents, so in my example code the most important is the article title than the sub title and the least important is the section main title.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- head stuff here-->
</head>
<body>
<header>
<!-- site name and logo and sitenav is here -->
</header>
<div id="section1">
  <div class="this_should_be_h_tag">
  Section 1 Main title
  <!-- for example this section is Called MENU (like restaurant menu) -->
  </div>
  <div id="section1_1">
    <div class="this_should_be_h_tag">
    Sub title 1
    <!-- for example this sub section is called HAMBURGERS -->
    </div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>
        Article title
        <!-- lets say this is called BBQ Burger -->
        </h1>
      </header>
      <div class="article-body">
      <!-- here is the description of the BBQ Burger -->
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </article>
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>
        Article title
        <!-- lets say this is called Vega Burger -->
        </h1>
      </header>
      <div class="article-body">
      <!-- here is the description of the Vega Burger -->
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div id="section1_2">
    <div class="this_should_be_h_tag">
    Sub title 2
    <!-- for example this sub section is called SPECIALITIES -->
    </div>
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>
        Article title
        <!-- lets say this is called Jalapeno Poppers -->
        </h1>
      </header>
      <div class="article-body">
      <!-- here is the description of the Jalapeno Poppers -->
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </article>
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>
        Article title
        <!-- lets say this is called Duckets -->
        </h1>
      </header>
      <div class="article-body">
      <!-- here is the description of the Duckets -->
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
<!-- footer stuff here -->
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

So in a structure like this what would be the correct path? Can I do something like this: section main title=h3, sub title=h2, and article title=h1?

Oh and I almost forgot the site title is also wrapped in a h1 tag.

EDIT:
So I added some HTML comment to clerify it little bit.
I hope it is now clear that the articles are the most important content and the second is the `Sub title` and the `Section Main title` is only a group name and probably totaly irrelevant from seo perspective, but it is in the original design which I don't want to change.

Comment: Seems pretty simple. H1 is the most important with H6 being the least. Style as needed.

Comment: Ok, so if I do it as I wrote so h3 > h2 > h1 order wouldn't that be wrong from seo perspective?

Comment: Section main titles should be h1, sub titles h2, and article titles h3 (or just header)

Comment: It is not clear at all what the actual structure of the page is, what you mean by “importance”, and what you mean by “correctly”. Besides, relying on “HTML5 outline” (which is what the code seems to be doing) is pointless.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela this is the actual structure, just stripped of code which is irrelevant for this question. And in importance I mean it is important for the site it selve and it is important for seo. I will put actual content and comments in html comments into my code above just to make it more clear, until than I wrote an example in a comment to `superUntitled's` answer

Comment: The structure of the *content* is not clear at all; you have only shown markup pattern. And “important for the site” does not answer the question what you mean by “important”.

Comment: I shown only a part of the markup because the site is currently down, and I posted only the parts which are in question. Important, so I don't know how can I define it correctly. The site is a food lets say blog but not really, so whats important is the title and the description of the food because the most people who are serching for food or recepies they search for keywords like the the titles of the articles. The sub titles are categrories and the section main title is a group name which separates this section from the rest of the content because it is a one page site.

Answer (score 0):

Section 1 main should be your `h1`. Subtitles should be `h2`. Article titles `h3`.

Search engines will index your site correctly. Just make sure your section and and sub-section headings are meaningfully named.

Comment: Ok, but sadly Section 1 main is the least meaningfull. here is a concrete example: Section 1 title=Menu, Subtitle 1=hamburgers, and the article titles of course are the names of the burgers. So no one on eart will search with 'Menu' keyword for a burger. And thats why I wanted a revers order. But it looks like I will have to change the structure or maybe completely dropp the Section 1 title or simply put it in a paragraph or span